# jquery using each function getting id values

Tags: jquery

I m generating a form dynamically and ids are also generated dynamically 
when i  select a drop down field it fires a  in a php page and gets the dynamic fields likeng

```
<input type="text" name="act" value="act_1">
<input type="text" name="act" value="act_2">
<input type="text" name="act" value="act_3">
```

i want to use a each function in jquery to get the value 
  I used but no use

```
$("input[id^='act_']").each(function() {


        });
```

Comment: Why are you searching for an id when the elements doesn't have the property at all?

Comment: @mark, you said dynamically ids are generated but your input fields do not have ids only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:   [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGFZb/1/)

```
$("input[name='act']").each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("input[value^='act_']").each(function() {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: And if the value is changed by the user ?

Comment: @dystroy I dont know about other browsers but on chrome the attribute value stays on the object http://jsfiddle.net/jwumm/

Answer (score 1):

Try with `name` because I didnt see your `id`,

```
$("input[name='act']").each(function() {

      var val = $(this).val();
      alert(val);
});
```

You can also try with `type` like

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
```

Or using value you can use like

```
$("input[value^='act_']").each(function() {
```

It will selects the inputs those values are started with `act_`

Comment: I doubt the real HTML would have the same name for many inputs.

Answer (score 0):

use the following instead

```
$("input[name='act']").each(function() {


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

such an html will not yield any result. Browser will certainly allow more than one elements with same name but when the form is submitted it will send only the first value to the server. In your example html the IDs are not showing up, but I hope you are generating them dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each($("input[value^='act_']"), function (index) {

    alert($(this).val());
});
```